# input value has to changes css

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have this html-code

```
<input id="red" type="text" value="120">
<div id="blue"></div>
```

and css

```
#blue{
margin-left: 120px
}
```

the purpose is that the value of margin-left is changing when the input is changing.

i was thinking to do it like below, but there's something not working:

```
(function ($) {
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#red').keyup(function () {
             var newMarginLeft = $('#red').val();
             $("#blue").css("margin-left",newMarginLeft);
         });
 }(jQuery));
```

Comment: `margin-left= 120px` is invalid. It should be `margin-left: 120px`. Next, `<input id=red" value=120>` is invalid as well, it should be `<input id="red" value="120" />` and you are missing the `type` attribute for `input` element.

Comment: sorry, i've corrected the html-code, it was a quick copy-paste. But my question is principal about the query.

Comment: You are passing the number without units, add `px` at the end :--------> `$("#blue").css("margin-left", newMarginLeft + 'px')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few syntactical problems with your jQuery. Here is the revised code:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#red').keyup(function (e) {
            var newMarginLeft = $('#red').val();
            $("#blue").css("margin-left", newMarginLeft+"px");
        });
   })
})(jQuery);
```

1. Be very aware of your braces and parentheses. You never closed your `.ready()` function and you had an extra parenthesis after you bound jQuery.
2. You must include units in your CSS assignment (px)

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vckve3aq/1/)

Answer (score 0):

First : Quotes around input value :

```
<input id="red" type="text" value="120">
```

Second : CSS should be like

margin-left : 120px ;

Third :In your jquery DOM ready should be:

```
(function($) {
   //
})(jQuery);
```

Fourth :Add units while manipulating css .

Answer (score 0):

You have to write

```
#blue{
margin-left: 120px
}
```

And also write `id = "red"`in input tag

Answer (score 0):

Here's a javascript solution:

```
window.onload = function() {
var a = document.getElementById('red');
a.addEventListener('keyup',function(){
document.getElementById('blue').style.marginLeft = document.getElementById('red').value+"px";
});
}
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/jzsgq3s1/)